# Parse Swift UITableView Accessory

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I have the following code, and now I am trying to implement accessory to the UITableView.
All the data is from Parse, even though there are tutorials out there helping out on how to do normal accessory, I am unable to find one that actually teaches on how to do that if I am getting data from online db like Parse.

```
//
//  Listdoctors.swift
//  ihealthtwo
//
//  Created by David on 10/1/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 ƒ. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class Listdoctors: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var listdoctors: UITableView!


    var doctorName = [String]()
    var doctorRate = [NSInteger]()
    var doctorDetail = [String]()


    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!




    func refresh()
    {
       let query = PFQuery(className: "doctors")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(

            {
                (listll: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    print("Successfully retrieved \(listll!.count) names of the lawyers.")
                    // Do something with the found objects
                    if let objects = listll {
                        for object in objects {
                            print(object)

                            self.doctorName.append(object["doctorName"] as! String)
                            self.doctorRate.append(object["Rate"] as! NSInteger)
                            self.doctorDetail.append(object["doctorContent"] as! String)


                            // print(object["Lawyer_Name"] as! String )
                            // self.lawyersname.append(object["Lawyer_Name"] as! String)
                            //self.lblName.text = object["Lawyer_Name"] as? String

                        }
                        self.listdoctors.reloadData()
                    }
                    print(self.doctorName.count)
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        })

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refrehsh")
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

        refresh()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return doctorName.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let doctorcell: doctorsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("doctorsproto") as! doctorsCell

        // Configure the cell...
        doctorcell.doctorname.text = doctorName[indexPath.row]
        doctorcell.doctorcontent.text = doctorDetail[indexPath.row]
         doctorcell.doctorrate.text = "\(doctorRate [indexPath.row])"

        //lawyercell.lblExpll.text = lawyerExp[indexPath.row]
        //lawyercell.lblPracareall.text = lawyerPracArea[indexPath.row]
        //profImages[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          //  if imageData != nil {
           //     let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            //    lawyercell.imageLawyer.image = image
           // }
           // else
           // {
            //    print(error)
           // } }

        return doctorcell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation to doctor detail

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier
        {
            switch identifier
            {
                doctor "TodoctorDetail":
                    let productDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! doctorDetail
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
                {

                }


            default: break
            }
        }ˍ
    }




    //MARK: - Helper Method


    //func productAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->?? (waht should i Put here)



}
```

My last line of code is not what I am sure what I exactly need to return, this is a example I am following from 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-E_EbMR9wA

Comment: Please add what are the problems that you are getting. Describe where do u get the error or where do u find the unsatisfying result. It will give us a better scenario to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I am not facing any errors at present. I am not even sure what to put there in my code. If I do face any errors I would be sure to put the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're trying to pass your data to a detail view which in this case you should be doing something like this assuming you have the proper indexPath and variables defined in the detailView already.

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if let identifier = segue.identifier
            {
                switch identifier
                {
                    doctor "TodoctorDetail":
                        let productDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! doctorDetail
                    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
                    {
                       // Assuming you have the proper indexPath defined here for the selected cell and that you have these three values already defined in your productDetailVC
                      productDetailVC.doctorName = doctorName[indexPath.row]
                      productDetailVC.doctorContent = doctorContent[indexPath.row]
                      productDetailVC.doctorRate = doctorRating[indexPath.row]
                    }


                default: break
                }
            }ˍ
        }
```

Comment: 2016-02-06 01:31:05.904 iLegaltwo[2737:155743] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7fd019ccd190>)
 Getting the above error.